# Deleting CardView Data from UI and Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews` which come from my Firebase Realtime Database for different activities, for example, daily meals. I have added a delete button to the `CardView` which I would like to implement a delete from UI and database function. I know how to do these both separately, but I am unsure how to update the database after deleting the `CardView` from the UI.

At the moment, it is deleting from UI but not database, so when I go back to the `activity`, the card reappears. Each meal has its own random ID, not sure if that makes a difference but thought it is important to note.

**Adapter Delete Function:**

```
    foodHolder.deleteMeal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            meals.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**Meal Activity (Where adapter is set):**

```
mealRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int total = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot mealSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String grams = mealSnapshot.child("grams").getValue(String.class);

                    if (grams == null) {
                        textViewFoodCounter.setText("0");
                    } else {
                        total += Integer.parseInt(grams);
                        textViewFoodCounter.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                    }

                    if (meals != null) {
                        noMealsImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        noMealsText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        noMealsImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        noMealsText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    progressBar.setMax(1000); // make dynamic
                    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", Integer.parseInt(grams))
                            .setDuration(300)
                            .start();

                    Meal data = mealSnapshot.getValue(Meal.class);
                    meals.add(data);
                }

                foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(meals);
                foodRecyclerView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

**CardView:**

[image]

**Firebase Meal Hierarchy:**

[image]

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here are some useful articles that might help. [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) and [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo, yes I ended up following a tutorial on YouTube to convert my RecyclerView into a FirebaseRecyclerView and implementer swipe to delete and also on button click :) Very complicated but got there in the end!

Comment: Good to hear that. If you found the solution, you might consider answering your own question. so future developers can benefit from it.

Comment: I will yes, good idea! Will do that sometime today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. If anything is updated in the firebase database you can load your new data using addValueEventListener and onDataChange.

```
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference;
    DatabaseReference dmoRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(serialId);

    dmoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                
            
           //get your updated data


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error fetching data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the issue I have is that it's not deleting from the Database, only the UI.. I don't know how to delete from the database via the Adapter..

Comment: You are not deleting from the firebase database. onclick your view holder delete button gets the unique id or name. Then you can do it like this.
` val mRealtimeDatabaseRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference  mRealtimeDatabaseRoot.child(uniqueID).removeValue() `

Comment: I dont know how to delete it from the Activity.. I can't get my database reference within my Adapter class to use the delete button.. if that makes sense? @Anwarchowdhury

Comment: You can try like this. Maybe not the best solution. but an easy way to do.
in the viewholder where you are getting id onclick. do this

       (view.context as MyActivity).deleteMeal(uniqueId) 
    
and then send it to activity like that.
In the activity receive it and delete it from firebase...   

  fun deleteMeal(uniqueId: String) {

       val mRealtimeDatabaseRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
 
      mRealtimeDatabaseRoot.child(uniqueID).removeValue() 
    }

Comment: Are you able to edit your answer to show what you mean exactly? I don't understand how to pass the data back to the activity from the adapter.. Sorry I am getting really overwhelmed with this as it's the very final thing to do for my university project.

Comment: add this from where you want to send ,in view holder --  (view.context as MyActivity).deleteMeal(uniqueId)

Comment: receive that in activity and delete the data , add this in activity--

fun deleteMeal(uniqueId: String) { 
val mRealtimeDatabaseRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference mRealtimeDatabaseRoot.child(uniqueID).removeValue()
 }